# cross compile libtheora with mingw

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile libtheora on an ubuntu 13.04 32 bit host for a windows 64bit using mingw.

I have installed mingw:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64
```

Downloaded and decompressed libogg-1.3.0 and libtheora-1.1.1

Compile libogg:

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
make
```

Compile libtheora:

```
./configure --disable-examples --without-vorbis --disable-oggtest \
  --with-ogg-includes=../libogg-1.3.0/include \
  --with-ogg-libraries=../libogg-1.3.0/src/.libs \
  --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

The result of the compilation is that:

```
libtool: link:  x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared .libs/libtheoradec-1.dll.def  .libs/apiwrapper.o .libs/bitpack.o .libs/decapiwrapper.o .libs/decinfo.o .libs/decode.o .libs/dequant.o .libs/fragment.o .libs/huffdec.o .libs/idct.o .libs/info.o .libs/internal.o .libs/quant.o .libs/state.o .libs/mmxidct.o .libs/mmxfrag.o .libs/mmxstate.o .libs/x86state.o      -o .libs/libtheoradec-1.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libtheoradec.dll.a
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: .libs/libtheoradec-1.dll.def:3: syntax error
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:.libs/libtheoradec-1.dll.def: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:.libs/libtheoradec-1.dll.def:2: syntax error
```

The first few lines of the libtheoradec-1.dll.def:

```
EXPORTS
EXPORTS^M
; Old alpha API^M
   theora_version_string @ 1^M
   theora_version_number @ 2^M
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is better to install your  `libogg-1.3.0` in some directory like  libogg_bin

`./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=(path to install)/libogg_bin`

`make`

`make install`

when u install the file permission and some other changes are made to compiled code

cd libtheora-1.1.1

`./configure --disable-examples --without-vorbis --disable-oggtest --with-ogg-includes=/path to-installed/include --with-ogg-libraries=/path to-installed/lib --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Comment: I agree this is better, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have u tried above one .. i tried with libogg-1.3.1 im able to compile without any error

Comment: Yes I have tried. I tried with libogg-1.3.1 as well. The compilation of libogg and install is ok, it's the second step (libtheora compilation) which doesn't work.

Comment: r u facing same problem?

Comment: Then its something other issue ... what ever i given above i tried im able to get it compiled without any error..

Comment: while trying wit your `./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
make` i too got error but i resolved it by using make install then i linked lib and include files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37941/discussion-between-yann-sagon-and-vinay-hunachyal)